# Set /p %foo% doesn't function as expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to make a "hacker tool" with the `tree` command. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
title $userOne ProxyMatrix
color a
echo Hello $userOne,
echo Please enter search function for today's commands:
set /p %commands%=""
:redo
echo Specify Storage Device
set /p %drive%=""
title $userOne ProxyMatrix: Running on %drive% drive at %random% bits per nano
color C
tree %drive% /f
:runagain
color a
echo Run again?
set /p %redo%=""
if %redo%="yes" goto redo
else if %redo%="y" goto redo
else if %redo%="Y" goto redo
else if %redo%="Yes" goto redo
else if %redo%="no" goto end
else if %redo%="No" goto end
else if %redo%="n" goto end
else if %redo%="N" goto end
else echo Thats not a valid answer!
pause
goto runagain
:end
echo Thank you for choosing InGen, inc.
pause
```

I realize that this won't "hack" anything, its more of a novelty. The problem is, the `set /p %redo%` and the if/else if statements don't work. They just quit the program. Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is `set /p variable=prompt`.

Instead of `set /p %redo%=""` write `set /p redo=""` or even better `set /p "redo="`

**EDIT**

your `if` syntax is broken too.

Syntax is: `if value1==value2 command` or `if value1==value2 (command1) else (command2)`

"Best Practice is to enclose both sides of the comparison with quotes (to avoid syntax errors with empty values or contained spaces):

```
if "%variable"=="value" echo yes
```

I would shorten the code to:

```
set /p %redo%=""
if /i "%redo:~0,1%"=="y" goto redo
if /i "%redo:~0,1%"=="n" goto end
else echo Thats not a valid answer!
```

`/i` tells `if` to ignore capitalization

`%variable:~0,1%` means "take a substring starting with the first letter (counting starts at `0`) with length=1 (so it takes the first letter)

(there is no `else` needed)

Comment: Thank you! This semi-works. Now, it gets stuck at my else ifs, saying something about expecting yes, but didn't. any suggestions?